# Display values in array variables (Java) in tabular format on web page (html)

Tags: java, arrays, html, tabular

I have written a Java program that has an array called list.
list has following variables and values:

```
list.get(0) = "Hi"; 
list.get(1) = "Hello";
list.get(2) = "How";
list.get(3) = "Are";
list.get(4) = "You";
list.get(5) = "Me";
list.get(6) = "They";
list.get(7) = "Them";
```

I want to display these values in the following format on a web page:

[image: Like this]

How do I achieve it?

Comment: Would simply outputting a .html file be all you need or are you looking to make a web app?

Comment: I want to make a web app.

Comment: Setting up a java web app can be pretty complicated.  If Java is not a hard requirement, a shorter, easier solution could be done with JavaScript.

Comment: Java is a requirement. But, how can this be achieved in javascript?

Comment: What if the array named "list" is being populated from a .txt file?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post any code snippets that you may be having an issue with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have JSP set up on your server, this will get you started.

```
<html>
<head><title>Mistletoe's Table</title></head>
<body>
    <table>
  <%
    String [] list = {"Hi", "Hello", "How", "Are", "You", "Me", "They", "Them"};
    for (int index = 0; index < list.length; index++) {
        if (index % 4 == 0) {
  %>
            <tr >
  <%
        }
  %>
      <td><%= list[index] %></td> 
  <%
    }
  %>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Mistletoe no problem!  If this works for you, please select it as the accepted answer.